# Running function inside gtk.main every 5 min using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

I tried to make a small panel indicator inside my ubuntu environment, so i wrote this script :

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess as notif
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator


APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, os.path.abspath('sample_icon.svg'), appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    gtk.main()

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    item_msgs = gtk.MenuItem('show msgs')
    item_msgs.connect('activate', msgs)
    menu.append(item_msgs)
    item_quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit.connect('activate', quit)
    menu.append(item_quit)
    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def msgs(_):
    notif.call(['notify-send','This is a new message !',])

def quit(_):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
main()
```

depending on [this one](https://gist.github.com/candidtim/5663cc76aa329b2ddfb5)

my problem is how to make `msgs()` function running inside `main()` function every 5 min or any other period time ?

Comment: my question in python3 and your answer in C language

Comment: [Glib.timeout_add](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add)